# Check if a string is of the 00:00,00 format with an annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, annotations

I'm building an mvc4 project in c#. I want to check if a field in my model class is filled in using the 00:00,00 format, like you can do with DateTime. Is there an annotation for a String field for this or will I have to create my own custom annotation?

Comment: What does your value represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}$")]
public string Stringy { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple RegEx will do it. The pattern is;

```
RegEx rgx = new RegEx("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}");
if (rgx.Match(inputString)) //we're good
```

What that's saying is; we need two digits (0-9) then a colon, then two digits more digits, then a comma, then two more digits. In RegEx values inside of [] are a group, an int inside of {} tells you how many repetitions are expected. The other characters in my expression are just literals.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a time measurement, couldn't you do something a bit cleverer than a regex?

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, 
                   DataFormatString      = @"{0:mm\:ss\,ff}")]
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
```

Comment: +1 - I was considering suggesting `DateTime.TryParse` and would certainly go that direction if I intend to do anything with the value.